# check rowwise if value in one column is present in multiple other columns R

Tags: r

brain stuck. i need to find a way to look for one column's rowwise value across multiple other columns, within the same row. like... 50 or 60. In the example below, "is rowwise value from A in B or C?" but using column positions within the actual data, not names of columns, as there are too many. i understand case_when would do the trick, but again too many columns to test.

example:

```
df1 <- data.frame(A = c(4, 6,3), 
                  B = c(4, 1, 1), 
                  C = c(1, 1, 3))
```

i tried this with map() but it seems to be looking in column 3 for any instance of number 4:59, not across columns 4 through 59.

```
nums <- c(4:59)
cols <- c(3)

wL$Check_Median <-
  wL[, cols] %>%
  map(~.x %in% nums) %>%
  reduce(`|`)
```

I imagined it would work, using 4:59 instead of named columns, something like this:

```
nums <- c(B:C)
cols <- c(A)

wL$D <-
  wL[, cols] %>%
  map(~.x %in% nums) %>%
  reduce(`|`)
```

and the result would be:

```
df2 <- data.frame(A = c(4, 6,3), 
                  B = c(4, 1, 1), 
                  C = c(1, 1, 3),
                  D = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution:

```
wL$D <- Reduce(`|`, lapply(wL[28:52], `==`, wL[,13]))
```